# How do I create a script that will use FTP to copy a file to another server?

Tags: python, bash, networking, ssh, ftp

I am an Network Engineer Apprentice and have been set a task that will copy a file from a server directory and use FTP to copy it to another location.  Essentially these are the steps that I would take:

1. Log in to NMS (Linux Box)
2. Change directory to /usr/lib/rancid/bin/clogin
3. Sudo rancid
4. clogin (IP Address of SVC)
5. change directory to disk:/ftp/reports/rogueaps
6. use FTP to copy the last created file to (IP Address)

As you can tell I am very new to this and only have about 2 months of experience in Networking and know very little about coding and scripting.  There is no rush to get this created and time is on my side.

This script will need to run once a day.  I do not expect anyone to create the script for me but pointing me in the right direction would be appreciated.  I am also able to use any language of my choice and I think python would be neat to learn.

Thank you

Comment: I'm no sys admin but a bash script timed with cron would be my choice. I love Python but for this type of job I think most of sys admins would use Perl, I don't know Perl much, I just did some migration stuff with it, like fixing some old repos and put them back to source control.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you should try to avoid FTP. If you can scp to the remote host, that would certainly be preferable.

If you need to stick to ftp, and if you have lftp as client available, you would probably do something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
nwd=/ftp/reports/rogueaps
user=rancid
passwd=VeRySecR3t
host=ip_of_SVC

cd /usr/lib/rancid/bin/clogin
lftp -u $user,$passwd $host <<EOF
cd $nwd
put $f
EOF
```

and put that in the crontab for the user rancid.

This is of course just a pointer to what you could do. In general, it is a bad idea to put passwords directly in the script. If you're courageous, you might try to get the uid/password from the .cloginrc in your script.

If that is not what you're looking for, you should look into expect. Clogin is basically an expect script that does some logins.